# Setup ethereum POS chain from scratch

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, nethermind

I want to setup my chain based on geth or nethermind with POS consensus, network should be started from scratch (Something like Ethereum 2.0 from scratch). Is it possible with consensus clients like Lighthouse, Nimbus, Prysm? Or another ways? Thanks for replies in advance!